Is it a good idea to include code from the relevant part of your compiler/interpreter in a question?
In my recent question, I included the relevant part of my compiler code in the question. Is that a good idea?

The question to ask when considering including implementation code is "does including it help people answer my question?". Essentially, does including the code make it easier for an answerer to understand your question and write an accurate answer.
For example, if you're asking a question about a specific implementation of a language, then yes, including implementation code is helpful (and kind of the point of asking such a question).
As another example, if you're asking a question about how you might generally implement something from a programming language, then including implementation code is a good idea if it acts as a reference or as an example of what you're asking. Basically, if the implementation demonstrates what you're looking for, it's a good idea.
As a final example, you're asking about a language design choice, then including implementation code probably isn't helpful.
Essentially, only include code if it's pertinent to the question and improves the answering experience. If it can be removed and the question still makes sense and can be easily answered, consider not including it.

In terms of your linked question, I personally believe it's a mostly good idea to include implementation code. While the question would have worked without it, the source code demonstrates a potential approach which answers can compare and contrast more "correct" approaches where applicable.

On the other hand, editing in a newer version of the code after the question has already been answered using the original version  seems to achieve nothing but bumping the question and can probably be avoided.
